# Problems with getting MDDropdown working with MDTopApp

Tags: kivy, kivymd

I am trying to implement a Menu dropdown in MDTopAppBar.  Kivy 2.2.1 kivymd 1.1.1

The demo code for this from the 1.2.0dev docs (https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/menu/index.html#usage) is as follows:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.metrics import dp

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu
from kivymd.uix.snackbar import Snackbar

KV = '''
MDBoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"

    MDTopAppBar:
        title: "MDTopAppBar"
        left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: app.callback(x)]]
        right_action_items: [["dots-vertical", lambda x: app.callback(x)]]

    MDLabel:
        text: "Content"
        halign: "center"
'''


class Test(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Orange"
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        menu_items = [
            {
                "text": f"Item {i}",
                "on_release": lambda x=f"Item {i}": self.menu_callback(x),
            } for i in range(5)
        ]
        self.menu = MDDropdownMenu(items=menu_items)
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def callback(self, button):
        self.menu.caller = button
        self.menu.open()

    def menu_callback(self, text_item):
        self.menu.dismiss()
        Snackbar(text=text_item).open()


Test().run()
```

This does not seem to work. It exhibits the dropdown but without text and does not respond to clicks in the dropdown.

I have experimented and gotten my code to exhibit the dropdown and apparently respond to clicks but I cannot get it to fire the callback function code. Here is my code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivymd.uix.toolbar import MDTopAppBar
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu

class BurstMonitorApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        #Create Screen
        screen = MDScreen()
       
        # dropdown=ObjectProperty(None)
        
        #Create Toolbar
        self.toolbar = MDTopAppBar(title="Burst Monitor Client")
        self.toolbar.pos_hint = {"top": 1}
        self.toolbar.right_action_items = [["menu", lambda x: self.dropdown.open()]]     
        screen.add_widget(self.toolbar)

        screen.add_widget(Image(source='KI2_logo.jpg', pos_hint={"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.7},size_hint=(0.2, 0.2)))
        self.textdisplay=MDTextField(text="Published messages appear here", 
                                     pos_hint={"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5},size_hint=(0.5, 0.1),
                                     font_size=18,multiline=True, readonly=True)
        screen.add_widget(self.textdisplay)

        # Create Dropdown Menu
        self.menu_items = [{"viewclass": "OneLineListItem", "text": "HFTAlert Twitter"},#{"leading_icon": "check"},#"callback": self.menu_callback},
                           {"viewclass": "OneLineListItem", "text": "KI2 Twitter"},#"callback": self.menu_callback},
                           {"viewclass": "OneLineListItem", "text": "KI2 Slack"},#"callback": self.menu_callback},
                           {"viewclass": "OneLineListItem", "text": "Console Only"}]#,"callback": self.menu_callback}]
        self.dropdown = MDDropdownMenu(caller=self.toolbar, items=self.menu_items, width_mult=4)
        self.dropdown.bind(on_release=self.menu_callback)

        return screen
    
    def menu_callback(self, instance_menu, instance_menu_item):
        print("Menu item selected")
        self.textdisplay.text = instance_menu_item.text
        return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    BurstMonitorApp().run()
```

Any advice would be much appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: Note, I know that the callback entries are commented out in the code above in lines like [{"viewclass": "OneLineListItem", "text": "HFTAlert Twitter"},#{"leading_icon": "check"},#"callback": self.menu_callback} ... the behaviour does not change with those entries included.